# How to make HTML component is not covered by footer menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` used to display contact information.
It is partially covered by FooterMenu.
How can I clear it? I can't scroll down more than this as shown in the image.

My css is

```
.contactrow{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 75%;
   min-height: 150px; 
   background-color: #CCFFFF;
   border-radius: 25px;
   color: #0000ff; 
}
```

The image is shown how it is covered at the bottom.
[image: img]

My html is

```
<div class = "row">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
<div class="contactrow" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; ">   
       <p>Please contact MyanmarTourism at</p>
       <p>email: admin@myanmartourism.com</p>
       <p>Phone: +1234567890</p>
       <p>Fax: +987654321</p>
    </div>
```

Edit:
My html for the whole page is shown. But only `<div>` since it is a long page.

```
<div class="carousel_pos" style="overflow-y: auto">
<div class = "container-fluid" >   
  <div class="row"> 

   </div ><!-- row -->   
</div> <!-- container-fluid -->
<!-- This is for Welcome Message -->
   <div class="row welcome">

   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   <!-- This is for Three Posts -->
    <div class="blocks" >
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1 p_1">



      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2 p_1" >



      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3 p_1">


      </div>
    </div><!-- blocks -->
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <div class="contactrow" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; ">   
       <p>Please contact MyanmarTourism at</p>
       <p>email: admin@myanmartourism.com</p>
       <p>Phone: +1234567890</p>
       <p>Fax: +987654321</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My page is implemented in Wordpress. So the footer has some wordpress codes.

```
<footer>        

            <!-- <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'secondary')); ?> -->
             <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
                  <div class="container"><!-- This is for sticky footer -->
                       <p class="navbar-text">Site built by Nyan</p>
                       <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                   <!-- This is for menus inside sticky footer -->
                       <?php
                  wp_nav_menu( array(
                       'menu'              => 'secondary',
                       'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
                       'depth'             => 2,                     
                       'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                       'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                       'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                  );
                       ?> 

                   </div>
            </div>     

             </div>
</footer>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to add a margin-bottom.

Comment: Could be usefull to see your full code, can you create a demo on codepen?

Comment: The code for your footer would be great to have too, as it is the footer that is overlapping.

Comment: ad `display:block; position:relative; height:auto;`
if still showing error so create a demo on jsfiddle then we can help you easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css:

```
.navbar {
    position: static;
}
```

Currently it is `position:fixed`.